# FileMaker: Match table value with corresponding picture from other table

Tags: filemaker

I've just started Using FileMaker Pro, I had been using Excel before and wrote it all in VBA, but I'm trying to achieve the same thing now in FileMaker.

So I have 2 layouts.

Layout 1 has a table that gets it data imported from a CSV file

Layout 2 has a table where the user can input data from FileMaker by clicking New Record

Layout 2 has 3 fields, 2 of them are dropdowns and the dropdown options are pulled from the first 2 columns of the table in Layout 1. The third filed is a container where the user can insert an image.

So I'm trying to make it so when the user selects a row in Layout 1, it will display a picture that matches the value in Layout 2.

If that doesn't make sense, let me try explaining with examples:

## Layout 1 has a bunch of rows of data:

**Car Make / Colour / Year / Country**

Fiat / Red / 2018 / France

Ford / Blue / 2010 / Germany

BMW / Green / 2017 / UK

## Layout 2 allows the user to input

**Car Make / Colour / Picture**

Drop down from 'Car Make' / Drop down from 'Colour' / Container to insert picture

Then when the user is on Layout 1 and clicks on a row that contains Fiat in the Car Make column, and Red in the Colour column, it will look at the corresponding picture from Layout 2.

So far I have made the 2 layouts, but I'm struggling to work out how to have them talk to each other. Is there a way to do it through FileMaker's UI or does it need to be scripted with an if statement somehow?

Would appreciate some advice and pointing in the right direction!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a relationship between the two tables. It's in the manage database/relationship panel.
Match by the criteria you choose and then you can display data from the related table in your layout.